# List the 5 most expensive toys ordened by price(Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a list of the 5 toys that have cost more money, in descending order if we have delivering each toy every single time.

For example, I have an Ipad that cost 600€ and is requested by child 1, 2 and 3. Now, I have a Nintendo that cost 300€ and is requested 3 times (1 time by child 1 and 2 times by the child 3). I have another toy (Laptop) that cost 360€ and is requested 8 times (2 times by child 1 and 6 times by child 3). Then, I must see:

1. Laptop because is requested 8 times and cost 360€ (in total 8 * 360€ = 2880€)
2. Ipad because is requested 3 times and cost 600€ (in total 3 * 600€ = 1800€)
3. Nintendo

When I have this, I want to see the child's data that more times request the same toy, for example, in case of Nintendo I would like see information about child 2. In case of laptop I would like see information about child 3.

I create this type:

```
CREATE TYPE ToysList AS (
t_Toy_name VARCHAR(255),
t_Price REAL,
t_Times_requested INTEGER,
t_Total_amount_money REAL,
t_Child_name VARCHAR(255),
t_Child_times_request SMALLINT,
t_Child_address VARCHAR(255),
t_Number_Siblings SMALLINT);
```

The tables are these:

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD(
child_id SMALLINT,
child_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_CHILD PRIMARY KEY(child_id),
CONSTRAINT VALID_GENDER CHECK (gender IN ('m', 'f')),
CONSTRAINT VALID_DATE CHECK (birth_date <= now())
);

CREATE TABLE letter (
letter_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
arrival_date DATE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
number_toys INTEGER NOT NULL,
child_id SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT valid_child_id CHECK ((child_id IS NOT NULL)),
CONSTRAINT PK_LETTER PRIMARY KEY(letter_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SIBLING(
child_id1 SMALLINT,
child_id2 SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_SIBLING PRIMARY KEY(child_id1, child_id2),
CONSTRAINT CHILD1_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id1) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD2_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id2) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);

CREATE TABLE TOY(
toy_id SMALLINT,
toy_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
price REAL NOT NULL,
toy_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
manufacturer VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_TOY PRIMARY KEY(toy_id),
CONSTRAINT POSITIVE_PRICE CHECK (price > 0),
CONSTRAINT VALID_TYPE CHECK(toy_type IN ('symbolic', 'rule', 'educational', 'cooperative', 'other'))
);

CREATE TABLE WISHED_TOY(
letter_id SMALLINT,
toy_id SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_WISHED_TOY PRIMARY KEY(letter_id, toy_id),
CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (letter_id) REFERENCES LETTER(letter_id),
CONSTRAINT TOY_FK FOREIGN KEY (toy_id) REFERENCES TOY(toy_id)
);
```

At this moment I did this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_top_Toys() RETURNS SETOF ToysList AS $$

DECLARE

l_Toy_name  VARCHAR(255);   
l_Price     REAL;       
l_Times_requested   INTEGER;--total times requested for this toy
l_Total_amount_money    REAL;   --total times requested * price toy
l_Child_name    VARCHAR(255);   
l_Child_times_request   SMALLINT;   --times request for the child
l_Child_address VARCHAR(255);
l_Number_Siblings   SMALLINT;

l_toy_id    INTEGER;
l_child_id  INTEGER;
l_letter_id INTEGER;

returnset ToysList;

BEGIN

FOR l_toy_id, l_Toy_name, l_Times_requested, l_Total_amount_money
IN SELECT t.toy_id, t.toy_name, COUNT(*), SUM(price) AS totalAmountMoney
    FROM toy t INNER JOIN wished_toy WT ON t.toy_id = WT.toy_id
    GROUP BY t.toy_id, t.toy_name
    ORDER BY totalAmountMoney DESC, t.toy_name
    LIMIT 5
LOOP
    returnset.t_Toy_name = l_Toy_name;
    returnset.t_Times_requested = l_Times_requested;
    returnset.t_Total_amount_money = l_Total_amount_money;

    SELECT c.child_id, c.child_name, c.address, SUM(L.number_toys) AS totalToys
    INTO l_child_id, l_Child_name, l_Child_address, l_Child_times_request
    FROM child c 
        INNER JOIN letter L ON c.child_id = L.child_id
        INNER JOIN wished_toy WIS ON WIS.letter_id = L.letter_id
    WHERE c.child_id = l_child_id
    GROUP BY c.child_id, c.child_name
    ORDER BY totalToys DESC
    LIMIT 1;

    returnset.t_Child_name = l_Child_name;
    returnset.t_Child_address = l_Child_address;
    returnset.t_Child_times_request = l_Child_times_request;

    SELECT COUNT(s.child_id2) AS numberSiblings
    INTO l_Number_Siblings
    FROM sibling s
        INNER JOIN child c1 ON c1.child_id = s.child_id1
    WHERE s.child_id1 = l_child_id
    LIMIT 1;

    returnset.t_Number_Siblings = l_Number_Siblings;

return next returnset; 

END LOOP; 

END; 

$$LANGUAGE plpgsql; 
COMMIT;
```

Can anyone say me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: I don't really understand the specification of the question when you say "if we have delivering each toy every single time", can you find a different way of stating this/say it again using different words? Feel free to post some sample data in your tables, and an example result of what you want- this can sometimes be easier way of specifying the query than to try and describe it in English :)

Comment: I edited the question. Please, can you check it? I hope it is better explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns setof type of data.  So, just select from it`s result, like this:

```
select * from list_top_Toys();
```

After that You can manipulate with results as it is table.
But, as I can see, this function needs much more changes.

Second query gives same results in every LOOP iteration, so I changed it to reflect result of first SELECT, and to make Letters table as leading in query.

At first, why group by toy_name - there need to be only group by toy_id.
Also, group by child_name (in first inner query) is redundant.
I would include toy_id in result set, it may be useful in later computations.
Also, You did not set toy price as you says in your post, so first SELECT have to have toy`s price.

So, my version of your function will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_top_Toys()
   RETURNS SETOF ToysList
   AS $$

DECLARE
   l_Toy_name  VARCHAR(255);   
   l_Price     REAL;       
   l_Times_requested   INTEGER;--total times requested for this toy
   l_Total_amount_money    REAL;   --total times requested * price toy
   l_Child_name    VARCHAR(255);   
   l_Child_times_request   SMALLINT;   --times request for the child
   l_Child_address VARCHAR(255);
   l_Number_Siblings   SMALLINT;

   l_toy_id    INTEGER;
   l_child_id  INTEGER;
   l_letter_id INTEGER;

   returnset ToysList;

BEGIN
   FOR l_toy_id, l_Toy_name, l_Price, l_Times_requested, l_Total_amount_money
   IN SELECT t.toy_id, t.toy_name, t.price, COUNT(*), SUM(price) AS totalAmountMoney
      FROM toy t
      INNER JOIN wished_toy WT ON t.toy_id = WT.toy_id
      GROUP BY t.toy_id
      ORDER BY totalAmountMoney DESC, t.toy_name
      LIMIT 5
   LOOP
      returnset.t_Toy_name = l_Toy_name;
      returnset.t_Price = l_price;
      returnset.t_Times_requested = l_Times_requested;
      returnset.t_Total_amount_money = l_Total_amount_money;

      SELECT c.child_id, c.child_name, c.address, SUM(L.number_toys) AS totalToys
      INTO l_child_id, l_Child_name, l_Child_address, l_Child_times_request
      FROM letter L
         INNER JOIN child c ON c.child_id = L.child_id
         INNER JOIN wished_toy WIS ON WIS.letter_id = L.letter_id
      WHERE wis.toy_id = l_toy_id
      GROUP BY c.child_id, c.child_name
      ORDER BY totalToys DESC
      LIMIT 1;

      returnset.t_Child_name = l_Child_name;
      returnset.t_Child_address = l_Child_address;
      returnset.t_Child_times_request = l_Child_times_request;

      SELECT COUNT(s.child_id2) AS numberSiblings
      INTO l_Number_Siblings
      FROM sibling s
         INNER JOIN child c1 ON c1.child_id = s.child_id1
      WHERE s.child_id1 = l_child_id
      LIMIT 1;

      returnset.t_Number_Siblings = l_Number_Siblings;

   return next returnset; 

   END LOOP; 
END; 
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I did not touch siblings query.

Comment: Thank you so much! I saw your changes and now I understand what I have been wrong.